# Custom Controller Not working in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

```
    <html ng-app>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body data-ng-controller="Myfunc">
    <ol type="i">
    <li data-ng-repeat="c in cust | filter:name"> {{ c.name | lowercase}} - {{c.city | lowercase}}</li>
    </ol>
   <script src="angular.js"></script>
   <script>

    function Myfunc($scope)
    {
    $scope.cust=[
    {name:'grimer',city:'ambernath'},
    {name:'primer',city:'goregaon'}
    ];
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

custom controller not working in angularjs 
don't know whether the custom script is working or not or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code and it is now working:

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

<div ng-app>
  <div data-ng-controller="Myfunc">
    <ol type="i">
      <li data-ng-repeat="c in cust | filter:name"> {{ c.name | lowercase}} - {{c.city | lowercase}}</li>
    </ol>

    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script>
      function Myfunc($scope) {
        $scope.cust = [{
          name: 'grimer',
          city: 'ambernath'
        }, {
          name: 'primer',
          city: 'goregaon'
        }];
      }
    </script>

  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

What I did is to move `ng-app` to a div and the `data-ng-controller="Myfunc"` to a div inside it.

You can find the working version at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/24899/) js_fiddle url.

Comment: Did you try out the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/24899/ ? Also I have used angular version 1.0.3

Comment: thank you sir i now tried with older version of .js and now its working but what might be the reason that it is not working with the new one ?

Comment: Where did you get the angular.js source?

Comment: No no no , I mean I wanted to check the exact file that you have, if you can provide me a link.

Comment: sir i have downloaded .js from this link itself first i was using the 1.5 version now i'm using 1.2 version

Comment: If I can find time I will investigate this for you. But until that moment, I suggest you to search the internet for the differences of those versions. And also you can check-out by changing your code part by part to find the working version and the not working one.